# Pass select option values as url parameter to next page

Tags: php, jquery, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I have custom registration system based on url parameters.

Step1: I have some buttons and when you click one of the buttons it will pass value to next page, where i'm able to get value by using `<?php echo $_GET['step1'];?>` (this works fine)

Step2: I want to use just two select boxes (don't want to use form here) and on `<a>` click I want to pass that selection to url.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<a href="http://domain/step1/step2?step1=<?php echo $_GET['step1'];?&SELECTboxVALUES>">Next</a>
```

So here is what I want to pass to the next page:

http://domain/step1/step2/step3?parameterfromstep1=something&gender=male&color=red

How should I make it? Should I use php on a button click or jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Submit the form using get, with Ajax

Comment: As i said in my question - i don't want to use form here :)

Comment: I would suggest you do use a form, and use Jquery to build the url and redirect. You wont be able to get the select box values using PHP without submitting the form

Comment: I'm working on a solution here, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Whats wrong with using a form with `method="GET"` it achieved the same result without any complications

Comment: @RiggsFolly By using form i'm getting "submited" in url + i didn't found method to pass 
earlier (in this case Get['step1']) parameters without using hidden inputs.

Comment: So use hidden inputs thats what they are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a id="next" href="http://domain/step1/step2?step1=<?php echo $_GET['step1'];?&SELECTboxVALUES>">Next</a>
```

use below code

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var gender = $('[name="gender"]').val();
    var color = $('[name="color"]').val();
    if( gender && color ){
        window.location.href = url+'?&'+gender+color;
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is maybe not the best or most beautiful approuch but i think the code below will work for you:

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<a href="http://domain/step1/step2/step3?step1=<?=$_GET['step1'];?>" id="nextButton">Next</a>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '#nextButton',function( event ) {

    // Stop default action
    event.preventDefault();

    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '&gender='+$('select[name="gender"] option:selected').text() 
                                     + '&color='+$('select[name="color"] option:selected').text();


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too :) but @Yash posted solution earlier and it works.

Comment: Np, didn't saw it. Good luck!